# Как еще добавить в начало файла следующее

Tags: c#, xml

Как еще добавить в начало xml файла при записи следующее?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
```

Мой код:

```
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));
//получаем поток, куда будем записывать сериализованный объект
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathXmlFileWrite + " ", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
  formatter.Serialize(fs, report);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите добавить [XmlDeclaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256048(v=vs.110).aspx) в начало файла.
Для задания настроек сериализации используется класс [XmlWriterSetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.110).aspx), который имеет параметры

- **OmitXmlDeclaration** - возвращает или задает значение, определяющее, следует ли опустить XML-объявление.
- **Encoding** - Возвращает или задает тип используемой кодировки текста.

Тогда ваш код будет иметь следующий вид

```
XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Report));

// объект, который сериализуем
Report obj = new Report();

//получаем поток, куда будем записывать сериализованный объект 
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathXmlFileWrite, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
   XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = false, Indent = true, Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")  });
   formatter.Serialize(writer, obj);
}
```

В настройках сериализации мы явно указали не удалять [XmlDeclaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256048(v=vs.110).aspx) и установили кодировку Latin1(ISO8859-1) через свойство Encoding.

Comment: А как эту декларацию считать с xml файла

Comment: @SVD102, поясните пожалуйста, куда вы хотите ее считать, и какую информацию вы хотите из нее получить?